# Issue on Sliding Thumbnails to Left or Right

Tags: jquery

Can you please take alook at this <kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/52VtD/2601/)**</kbd> and let me know why I am not able to Slide the Thumbnails to Left or right?

What I was trying to do is sliding one thumbnail on each click until to get the last thum at the `galley`

Here is the code that I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    // Gallery
    if(jQuery("#gallery").length){

        // Declare variables
        var totalImages = jQuery(".gallery > li").length, 
            imageWidth = jQuery(".gallery > li:first").outerWidth(true),
            totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
            visibleImages = Math.round(jQuery(".gallery").width() / imageWidth),
            visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
            stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery").width(totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery-prev").click(function(){
            if(jQuery(".allery").position().left < 0 && !jQuery(".gallery").is(":animated")){
                jQuery(".gallery").animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });

        jQuery("#gallery-next").click(function(){
            if(jQuery(".gallery").position().left > stopPosition && !jQuery(".gallery").is(":animated")){
                jQuery(".gallery").animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have a lot of type errors in javascript.
I've found few errors and corrected them. Please try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    // Gallery
    if($(".gallery").length) {

        // Declare variables
        var totalImages = jQuery(".gallery > ul > li").length, 
            imageWidth = jQuery(".gallery > ul > li:first").outerWidth(true),
            totalWidth = imageWidth * totalImages,
            visibleImages = Math.round(jQuery(".gallery").width() / imageWidth),
            visibleWidth = visibleImages * imageWidth,
            stopPosition = (visibleWidth - totalWidth) + imageWidth;
        jQuery(".gallery").width(visibleWidth);    
        jQuery(".gallery > ul").width(totalWidth);

        jQuery("#gallery-prev").click(function() {
            if(jQuery(".gallery > ul > li").position().left < 0 && !jQuery(".gallery").is(":animated")) {
                jQuery(".gallery > ul > li").animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });

        jQuery("#gallery-next").click(function() {
            if(jQuery(".gallery > ul > li:first").position().left > stopPosition && !jQuery(".gallery").is(":animated")) {
                jQuery(".gallery > ul > li").animate({left : "-=" + imageWidth + "px"});
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

});
```

And css:

```
.gallery > ul {
    overflow-x: hidden;    
    width: 3000px;
}
.col-sm-3 {
    width:265px;   
}
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/2603/

Comment: Thanks I got but there is just one issue here, it look like endless sliding even if there is no more item to slide! can you please let me know why this is happening?